# Emscripten makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, emscripten, emmake, emcmake

I am trying to create `emscripten` logic in `Makefile` . I am calling `cmake` command of a `CMakeLists.txt`.
So the logic looks like this

```
ifeq(EXECUTOR, Emscripten)
    emcmake cmake cmake/CMakeLists.txt
else
   cmake cmake/CMakeLists.txt
endif
```

And in `CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Emscripten)
    // Do some logic
endif()
```

So it is crucial to detect this `ifeq(EXECUTOR, Emscripten)`
How can I do that?

Comment: Well, the string `EXECUTOR` will never be equal to the string `Emscripten`, like the string `foo` is never equal to `bar`.  Since you don't give any other information, it's hard to say what you really wanted to do.

Comment: @MadScientist In other words I need to detect emscripten in makefile

Comment: What I mean is, if you want to compare the **CONTENTS** of the variable `EXECUTOR` you have to reference it, like `ifeq ($(EXECUTOR),Emscripten)`.  In cmake you can avoid using the `${...}` because cmake will infer that the value should be a variable name but make never does that.  If you want the variable you have to reference it.  Else you're just comparing the plain string `EXECUTOR`, not a variable named `EXECUTOR`.  If what you're asking is how to figure out what the value of `EXECUTOR` should be and how to set it, you have to do it yourself.  Make doesn't do anything like that for you.

Comment: Note that in your cmake file a simple `if (EMSCRIPTEN)` should work as well.